# How can I link to an Asset from the Rich Text editor?

Tags: assets, redactor

I have some content on my entry like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis rutrum dolor.
```

I know I can link to an Entry or Category, but I would like to link to an Asset. For example, a PDF.

I would like to highlight `Lorem ipsum` and link that text to a PDF. I can change over to HTML view and manually enter the link, but that seems risky to ask a client who may not know any HTML. Is there a preferred way to select some text and link it to an asset?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't really related to Craft specifically, but to allow a user to link to an asset, you will need to enable the feature in the redactor configuration file.

For example, within this file:

```
/craft/config/redactor/Standard.json
```

You will see something like this:

```
{
    "buttons": [
    "html",
    "formatting",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    ...
```

You will need to add `file` to that list so that it looks like this:

```
    {
    "buttons": [
    "html",
    "formatting",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "file"
    ...
```

Make sure to clear out your cache to make sure that Craft can see your updated file.

Now when you highlight some text, you can choose "file" and then select an asset from one of your asset sources.